# Theme check warning about text domain

Tags: themes, warnings, textdomain

While running theme check plugin in my theme, it shows a warning [More than one text-domain is being used in this theme.The domains found are industrypro-thecreo,]but I am using only one text domain which is 'industrypro-thecreo'.Even the warning also shows one text domain name. I have checked the spelling,space of text domain.All are ok. What could be the possible reason of this warning?
Thanks

Comment: Could you have an empty text domain (aka `_('foo', '')`)? "industrypro-thecreo," - notice the "," and empty space behind

Comment: I have a same problem . I defined my textdomain once in `functions.php` such as : `load_theme_textdomain('material', get_template_directory() . '/languages');`.
and I do not used empty text domain in my codes